# JavaFX + MySQL SIGN IN method not working

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Every time I run this code I get a "Wrong Credentials" alert, as if the program is not even checking the SQL database.

```
public static void studentSignIn(ActionEvent event, String email, String password) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/compsciia", "root", "toor");
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM students WHERE email = ?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    if (resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setContentText("Wrong credentials");
        alert.show();
    } else {
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            do {
                String retrievedPassword = resultSet.getString("password");

                if (retrievedPassword.equals(password)) {
                    sceneChange(event, "StudentPage.fxml", email);
                }
            } while (resultSet.next());
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setContentText("Provided credentials are incorrect");
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing the SQL code, played around with the if statements, looked online, but nothing.

Comment: this is basically unrelated to javafx: fix the login issue in a stand-alone non-ui application with hard-coded values, f.i., only after that's working go on to add ui for dynamic input.

Answer (score 3):

In JDBC, a `ResultSet` is always initially in a state where the cursor points *before* the first row. That will always be the case until you call `next()`. (If there is no result, then it will still be the case.) So your first `if` condition

```
if (resultSet.isBeforeFirst())
```

will always be true.

If `email` is unique in the database (i.e. you can be assured of at most one result in the result set) the logic is:

- Call `resultSet.next()`
- If that returns true, there's a row in the database, so check the password and show the appropriate alert depending on whether or not it matches
- If it returns false, there is no row in the database with that email

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    String retrievedPassword = resultSet.getString("password");
    if (retrievedPassword.equals(password)) {
        sceneChange(event, "StudentPage.fxml", email);
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setContentText("Provided password is incorrect");
        alert.show();
    }
} else {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setContentText("Provided email is not in the system");
    alert.show();        
}
```

If the database contains multiple copies of the same email (presumably with different passwords), then the logic is a little more complex, as you have to check all possible results:

```
boolean loginCorrect = false;
boolean foundEmail = false;

while (resultSet.next() && (!loginCorrect)) {
    foundEmail = true;
    String retrievedPassword = resultSet.getString("password");
    loginCorrect = retrievedPassword.equals(password);
}

if (loginCorrect) {
    sceneChange(event, "StudentPage.fxml", email);
} else if (foundEmail) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setContentText("Provided password is incorrect");
    alert.show();
} else {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setContentText("Provided email is not in the system");
    alert.show();        
}
```

The usual slightly off-topic caveats here:

- You need to close all the database resources. I didn't include that in the code.
- This is not production quality but just for demonstration purposes. In the real world you should not store passwords in plain text but should store them digested and test the digested password against the database store.